# Generic datatype Array creation where the type is inner class

Tags: java, generics, types

I have a class Table, which is declared with generic types K and V. Those are used as data type for parameters of inner class Node of which i am attempting to create the actual Array of. The relevant code of class Table is as follows:

```
public class Table<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements ITable<K,V> {
    private int numberOfElements;
    private boolean sorted;
    private Node[] list;

    //inner class
    private class Node{
        K key;
        V value;
        public Node(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    //constructor
    public Table(Class<Node> c){
        this.numberOfElements = 0;
        sorted = false;
        list = (Node[])Array.newInstance(c,1000);
        this.list = list;
    }
```

However when in actual code elsewhere I try to call a constructor of Table with concrete data type (City being my own class with int and String parameters) like so:

```
 Table<Integer,City> table = new Table<Integer,City>(city.getClass());
```

I get an error : `Class<CAP#1> cannot be converted into class <Table<Integer,City>.Node> CAP#1 extends City from capture of ? extends City`.

I am assuming this has to do with Node being inner class of Table not present in Table class declaration, but actual solution to this problem eludes me, as I have no idea how to approach generic datatype arrays. And yes, it has to be an array, it is written in exercise description.

EDIT: Adding the City class. It is a simple class with only two parameters.

```
public class City {
    public String name;
    public int ID;

    public City(String name, int iD) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ID = iD;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getiD() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setiD(int iD) {
        this.ID = iD;
    }
}
```

I intended for the Node to basically contain the instance of City as value and the ID of the instance as key to easily pull it for searches. I have already made this exercise with custom data structure so i know the approach works, but i am stuck on inability to properly declare the generic datatype array

Comment: Why is your `public Table(Class<Node> c){` parameter `Class<Node> c`? And why are you passing `city.getClass()` which represents `Class<City>`? Based on fact that you are calling constructor like `new Table<Integer,City>(city.getClass());` shouldn't it be declared as `public Table(Class<V> c){`?

Comment: I have no idea if that would work as i intended it. While the V value in node does indeed contain the City class instance, i need the K key for searching method in Table and i do not know how i would extract the K from V value. To my rather limited knowledge(i am still doing basic school exercises after all) it is not possible. The fact that i used wrong parameter for constructor did not occur to me. Or rather, it did, but i thought it was wrong for entirely different reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `Array.newInstance`, since the component type is statically know, it is `Node`. In the constructor, you can't do this:

```
this.list = new Node[1000];
```

Because this implicitly uses `Table<K, V>.Node`, which is generic and you can't create a generic array. But you can force it to be a raw type by using:

```
this.list = new Table.Node[1000];
```

And then removing the `Class<Node>` parameter from the constructor you can call it like:

```
Table<Integer, City> table = new Table<>();
```

You will get an unchecked warning for converting from a raw array type to a generic one (as explained by newacct in the comments), which you can safely suppress.

Comment: "You will get an unchecked warning for using a raw type as the array component type" I don't think there is ever a warning for using a raw type as an array component type. Rather, the warning is for the assignment which involves an unchecked conversion from `Table.Node[]` to `Table<K,V>.Node[]`

Comment: @newacct Ah, you're right. Trying out `int i = new Class[0].length;` doesn't issue a warning.